# Similarity solutions and similarity variables for heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

What are similarity solutions and similarity variables in the context of PDEs? I have looked at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similar_solution), but how can I use this to find solutions of the 1-dimensional heat equation $u_t = D u_{xx}$? Maybe somebody can give literature on this topic.